# Servlet includes response after forward is it expected

Tags: java, servlets

Servlet includes response after forward is it expected? Find the code below in my servlet. Here print.html contains only "say Hello to print". My expectation here that i should get response only "say Hello to print". 
But i get response "say Hello to print" and "add in response after forward" also. is it expected?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
   resp.setContentType("text/html");
   PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
   req.getRequestDispatcher("/test/print.html").forward(req, resp);
   writer.println("add in response after forward");
}
```

Comment: It is. `forward` simply lets another servlet generate a response (write to a stream). It doesn't stop request handling. You can still do more (or a limited subset) of operations on the response.

Answer (score -1):

[image: This image says all about the forward method]

What forward method does is, it redirects you to different page with the current request and response object and final response is thus returned by redirected page.

consider an example, you submitted the form to some servlet say "XYZ" now you want to process some data of that for in "XYZ" and after that you want to do remaining processing in servlet "PQR". This is the main significance of calling forward method with current request and response object

Ask in comments if you have any other doubt.

Reference link: http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher-in-servlet

```
Happy Coding!!
```